# Group fields by year Views Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, group-by, view

I want to group fields by a field called `field_yea` using Views in Drupal 7.

I used the `Group by` checkbox under Advanced Settings and selected Grouping field: `field_year` under Style options. 

But the output is still:

```
2011
Content
2011
Content
2010
Content
```

instead of:

```
2011
Content
Content
2010
Content
```

What am I doing wrong?

Attached are screenshots from my Views settings and the content type I am using.

I really don't know why this is not working.

[Screenshot Views Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NeVs.png)

[Screenshot Content Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScIm9.png)

Answer (score 4):

Since Views 7.x-3.2+ you can just turn on the option "Remove tags from rendered output". It works with the RDF module enabled.

You can see an screenshot on http://drupal.org/node/1235994#comment-5606370

Answer (score 1):

Another comment on drupal should help:
http://drupal.org/node/1253562#comment-4886998

Just disable the RDF-Module. After disabling and resaving the date formats it worked like a charm (Drupal 7.8 - Views 7.x-3.0-rc1 - date 7.x-2.0-alpha4).

Comment: In Drupal 7.10 just turning off of the RDF module solve the problem. Without resaving the date formats.

Answer (score 1):

As per the links posted, you don't actually have to disable the RDF module. What you need to make sure you do, is under the View display, in Format->Settings, make sure the "Use rendered output to group rows" and "Remove tags from rendered output" are both checked.

Also make sure you are using the latest stable version of Views, Ctools, and Date module. Hope that can help.